# do i need to replace the tire

Tags: tires

[image]i hit a curb was wondering does it look like I need to replace the tire thanks

Comment: This is a seriously old question, and tire health is seriously off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will need to replace the tire.  Damage to the thin side wall can be very dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the picture but it *might* be just the rim protector that's taken the hit given there's no obvious sign of a bulge or similar.

Even though the rim protector itself isn't structural to the tire I certainly wouldn't be taking any chances with it - if there were to be any further impacts or stresses on that area then it would most likely fail.

Get it changed ASAP and as blacksmith37 and Paulster2 state you'll need to make sure the rim is OK as well. Vibrations through the steering wheel and/or pressure loss could be indications of dents to the rim.

Answer (score 0):

From the photo it looks like you may have dented the rim; the scratches can be ground and sanded easily enough but a dent is more serious. I would replace the tire and not wonder about it. When I had this problem , the tire shop had trouble balancing the wheel because there was a dent that was not apparent to the eye.

Comment: Rims can be "trued" if taken to the right place. Most dents are repairable (even severe ones), but will cause havoc (balance and vibration) if not taken care of.

Comment: Discount Tire said there was no chance. It was a hassle getting a wheel for less the the dealers crazy $700.

Comment: Really, that's one person at "Discount Tire"'s opinion. Take it for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Like a previously mentioned comment, if it is on the thinner side of the tire you can risk the tire rupturing in use, or when it heats up. That being said, if it is like a "chip" then it doesn't matter and you don't have to replace it. My dad did the same thing with his 2014 Toyota Carolla and he went to go replace the tires but the person who they sent him to told him that he didn't really need to get them replaced.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).